# Translating 1612 Dutch marriage record

Tags: palaeography, marriage-records, 17th-century, translation, netherlands

This 1612 marriage record from Leyden is for my 10x great-grandparents George Morton and Juliana Carpenter, both born in England. Sadly, my Dutch is limited to guessing based on my poor German, and this handwriting is a challenge!

Can anyone translate this?

[image: my]

Comment: I've sent it off to my Dutch uncle. Although he has left Holland over 50 years ago, he remains fluent in the language. Hopefully he will be able to help. I'll advise as soon as I hear from him. (I'm currently away on vacation).

Comment: It will be interesting to compare original Dutch text to the scan... Could you provide it in the question?

Comment: @GeorgeGaál the transliteration and more info is at http://stoltzfamily.us/2017/08/15/a-dutch-romance/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got a translation. For the record:

> The first the 7th July 1612
>
> The second the 14th July 1612
>
> The third the 21st of July 1612
>
> Are married before Frans Adriaensz. van Leewen and Jacob Paedts
>   aldermen this 23rd [22nd?] July 1612
>
> Registered The fourth of July 1612
>
> George Morton, Englishman from York in England, a young man and
>   merchant, accompanied by Thomas Morton, his brother, and Roger Wilson,
>   [?] his acquaintance, with Juliana Carpenter, young daughter from Bath
>   also lying in England, accompanied with Alexander Carpenter her
>   father, Alice Carpenter her sister, and Agnes Robinson [?] her
>   acquaintance.